# Get top 10 products for every category

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, rank

I have a query which is something like this

```
SELECT 
t.category, 
tc.product, 
tc.sub-product,
 count(*) as sales 
 FROM tg t, ttc tc
 WHERE t.value = tc.value
 GROUP BY t.category, tc.product, tc.sub-product;
```

Now in my query I want to get top 10 products for every category (top by sales ) and for every category I need top 5 sub category (top by sales)

You can assume the problem statement as something like this :

Get top 10 products for each category by sales and for each product get top 5 sub-products by sales .

- Here category can be  Books
- Product can be Harry Porter book
- sub productcan be HarryPorter series 5

Sample input data format

```
category |product |subproduct |Sales [count (*)]

abc   test1    test11     120

abc   test1    test11     100

abc   test1    test11     10

abc   test1    test11     10

abc   test1    test11     10

abc   test1    test11     10

abc   test1    test12     10

abc   test1    test13     8

abc   test1    test14     6

abc   test1    test15     5

abc   test2    test21     80

abc   test2    test22     60

abc   test3    test31     50

abc   test3    test32     40

abc   test4    test41     30

abc   test4    test42     20

abc   test5    test51     10

abc   test5    test52     5 

abc   test6    test61     5 

|

|

|

bcd   test2    test22     10 

xyz   test3    test31     5 

xyz   test3    test32     3 

xyz   test4    test41     2
```

Output would be "

```
top 5 rf for (abc) -> abc,test1(289) abc,test2 (140), abc test3 (90), abc test4(50) , abc test5 (15)

top 5 rfm for (abc,test1) -> test11(260),test12(10),test13(8),test14(6),test15(5) and so on
```

My query is failing because results are really huge . I am reading about oracle analytic functions like rank. Can someone help me modifying this query using analytical functions. Any other approach can also work.

I am referring to this http://www.orafaq.com/node/55. But unable to get a right sql query for this.

Any help would be appreciated..I am like stuck for 2 days on this :(

Comment: Are looking for a solution in `MySql` or `oracle`?

Comment: What is the difference ? My database is oracle but I follow same MySql syntax for queries.

Comment: MySQL does not support analytical functions, so any solution involving them will not work on MySQL

Comment: @TopCoder: Oracle and MySQL have different SQL syntaxes.

Comment: Okay.. In that case I am looking for oracle query.

Comment: where does the 3000 limit fit in the overall query?

Comment: 3000 is to get all these things done for top 3000 stores.We can ignore it aswell.  Let me edit it so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Someone might be better able to help if you posted the `create table` statements for the tables along with a few sample data. I never understand why there are sql questions where someone goes into great lengths trying to describe what he has and what he wants, but wouldn't use DDL and DML to describe exactly that.

Comment: And: that SQL statement isn't even valid. Edit: Ah! Now it is, but I don't see an inner query. Let's just wait until all the information is there.

Comment: Well, where's the sales table?

Comment: Sorry but I tried to frame the question a little better .Can someone please look into it now and let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Some clearer table names would help.  I can appreciate conciseness, but more than two or three characters would help us understand the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably reasons not to use analytical functions, but using analytical functions **alone**:

```
select am, rf, rfm, rownum_rf2, rownum_rfm
from
(
    -- the 3nd level takes the subproduct ranks, and for each equally ranked
    -- subproduct, it produces the product ranking
    select am, rf, rfm, rownum_rfm,
      row_number() over (partition by rownum_rfm order by rownum_rf) rownum_rf2
    from
    (
        -- the 2nd level ranks (without ties) the products within
        -- categories, and subproducts within products simultaneosly
        select am, rf, rfm,
          row_number() over (partition by am order by count_rf desc) rownum_rf,
          row_number() over (partition by am, rf order by count_rfm desc) rownum_rfm
        from
        (
            -- inner most query counts the records by subproduct
            -- using regular group-by. at the same time, it uses
            -- the analytical sum() over to get the counts by product
            select tg.am, ttc.rf, ttc.rfm,
              count(*) count_rfm,
              sum(count(*)) over (partition by tg.am, ttc.rf) count_rf
            from tg inner join ttc on tg.value = ttc.value
            group by tg.am, ttc.rf, ttc.rfm
        ) X
    ) Y
    -- at level 3, we drop all but the top 5 subproducts per product
    where rownum_rfm <= 5   -- top  5 subproducts
) Z
-- the filter on the final query retains only the top 10 products
where rownum_rf2 <= 10  -- top 10 products
order by am, rownum_rf2, rownum_rfm;
```

I used rownum instead of rank so you don't ever get ties, or in other words, ties will be randomly decided.  This also doesn't work if the data is not dense enough (less than 5 subproducts in any of the top 10 products - it may show subproducts from some other products instead).  But if the data is dense (large established database), the query should work fine.

---

The below makes two passes of the data, but returns correct results in each case. Again, this is a rank-without-ties query.

```
select am, rf, rfm, count_rf, count_rfm, rownum_rf, rownum_rfm
from
(
    -- next join the top 10 products to the data again to get
    -- the subproduct counts
    select tg.am, tg.rf, ttc.rfm, tg.count_rf, tg.rownum_rf, count(*) count_rfm,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tg.am, tg.rf order by 1 desc) rownum_rfm
    from (
        -- first rank all the products
        select tg.am, tg.value, ttc.rf, count(*) count_rf,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 1 desc) rownum_rf
        from tg
        inner join ttc on tg.value = ttc.value
        group by tg.am, tg.value, ttc.rf
        order by count_rf desc
        ) tg
    inner join ttc on tg.value = ttc.value and tg.rf = ttc.rf
    -- filter the inner query for the top 10 products only
    where rownum_rf <= 10
    group by tg.am, tg.rf, ttc.rfm, tg.count_rf, tg.rownum_rf
) X
-- filter where the subproduct rank is in top 5
where rownum_rfm <= 5
order by am, rownum_rf, rownum_rfm;
```

columns:

```
count_rf : count of sales by product
count_rfm : count of sales by subproduct
rownum_rf : product rank within category (rownumber - without ties)
rownum_rfm : subproduct rank within product (without ties)
```

Comment: what does rowmun_rf2 and rownum_rfm returns to me. Can you please add little explanation to this ?

Comment: This is not working for me. Can you please verify . I am unable to trace it back.

Answer (score 0):

It's guesswork, but you could probably start from something like this:

```
drop table category_sales;
```

Some test data:

```
create table category_sales (
   category    varchar2(14),
   product     varchar2(14),
   subproduct  varchar2(14),
   sales       number
);

begin

  for cate in 1 .. 10 loop
  for prod in 1 .. 20 loop
  for subp in 1 .. 30 loop

      insert into category_sales values (
             'Cat '  || cate,
             'Prod ' || cate||prod,
             'Subp ' || cate||prod||subp,
              trunc(dbms_random.value(1,30 + cate - prod + subp))
      );

  end loop; end loop; end loop;

end;
/
```

The actual query:

```
select * from (
  select 
    category,
    product,
    subproduct,
    sales,
    category_sales,
    product_sales,
    top_subproduct,
    -- Finding best products within category:
    dense_rank () over (
      partition by category
      order     by product_sales desc
    ) top_product 
  from (
    select 
      -- Finding the best Subproducts within
      -- category and product:
      dense_rank () over (
         partition by category, 
                      product 
         order     by sales desc
      )                             top_subproduct,
      -- Finding the sum(sales) within a 
      -- category and prodcut
      sum(sales) over (
         partition by category, 
                      product
      )                             product_sales,
      -- Finding the sum(sales) within 
      -- category
      sum(sales) over (
         partition by category
      )                             category_sales,
      category,
      product,
      subproduct,
      sales
    from
      category_sales
  )
)
where 
--    Only best 10 Products
      top_product       <= 10 and
--    Only best 5 subproducts:
      top_subproduct    <= 5
-- "Best" categories first:
order by 
      category_sales desc,
      top_product    desc,
      top_subproduct desc;
```

In that query, the column `category_sales` returns the *sum of sales* of the category in whose record it is returned. That means, every record of the same category has the same `category_sales`. This column is needed to order the result set with the best (sales) categories first (`order by ... category_sales desc`).

Similarly, `product_sales` is the *sum of sales* for a category-product combination. This column is used to find the best *n (here:10)* products in each category (`where top_product <= 10`).

The column `top_product` is "created" with the `dense_rank() over...` analytical function. For the best product in a category,it's 1, for the second best it's 2 and so on (hence the `where top_product <= 10`.

The column`top_suproduct` is calculated in a similar fashion like `top_product` (that is with `dense_rank`).

Comment: I am running this query on data warehouse so there is no option of creating a new table.

Comment: This table is *obviously* not meant to be created! It should rather give you an idea on how to proceed further.

Comment: Got it! Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: what does these three values return to me category_sales,    product_sales,    top_subproduct, ?