# Write an Oracle query to get top 10 products for top 5000 stores

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get top 10 products for every category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966905/get-top-10-products-for-every-category)

I am looking for an Oracle query to get top 5000 stores and for each store get top 10 products and for each top 10 products get top 5 sub-products. So In total I should get 5000*10*5 rows.

Can someone help me get this using Oracle's analytical functions.

My current query looks like

```
SELECT 
store,
product, 
sub-product,
 count(*) as sales 
 FROM stores_data
 GROUP BY store, product, sub-product;
```

Please assume table names as stores_data with columns store_id , product,sub_product

Comment: Please post the code you have written.

Comment: I am referring to this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966905/get-top-10-products-for-every-category but it doesnot work for me.

Comment: any help would be appreciated . I am struggling for around 2 days now.

Comment: Why do you ask a new/the same question again without even referring to the previous question and without posting some code? It could possibly save me a lot of typing if I knew what has been tried before.

Comment: Might as well close it as duplicate too.

Comment: I did add my comments in last question but no one replied back. so I am asking the new one.

Comment: @Top: that's not how we do it here.

Comment: -1 for asking same question again

Comment: Duplicate of [Get top 10 products for every category](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4966905/255257)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use dense_rank to get the top N rows.

Something like

```
SELECT
  storeid,
  store,
  productid,
  product,
  subproductid,
  subproduct
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      s.storeid,
      s.store,
      p.productid,
      p.product,
      sp.subproductid,
      sp.subproduct,
      dense_rank() over ( order by s.storeid) as storerank,
      dense_rank() over ( partition by s.storeid 
                          order by p.productid) as productrank
      dense_rank() over ( partition by s.storeid, p.productid 
                          order by sp.subproductid) as productrank
    FROM
      stores s
      INNER JOIN products p on p.storeid = s.storeid
      INNER JOIN subproduct sp on sp.productid = p.productid
  ) t
WHERE
  t.storerank <= 5000 and
  t.productrank < 10 and
  t.subproductrank < 5
```

Of course, I don't now your tables nor the relation between them. And the actual fields and conditions you want to check for, so this is just a simple query getting the top N records based on their id. Also, this query expects a product to have only one store which might not be the case.. At least it will show you how to use `dense_rank` to get a three-layered sorting/filtering.

Comment: I just have one table. stores_data which has store_name,product,sub_product .

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the other answer because that looks more like how such a table structure *should* be, I think.

But you described in your other thread to have a table that looks like this:

```
create table store_data (
  store varchar2(40), 
  product varchar2(40), 
  subproduct varchar2(40), 
  sales int);
```

That actually looks like data that is aggregated already and that you do now want to analyze again. You query could look like this. It first aggregates the sum of the sales, so you can order shops and products by sales too (the sales in the table seem to be for the subproducts. After that, you can add ranks to the shops and products by sales. I added a rank to the subproducts too. I used rank here, so there is a gap in the numbering when more records have the same sales. This way, when you got 8 records with a rank of 1, because they all have the same sales, the 6th record will actually have rank 9 instead of 2, so you will only select the 8 top stores (you wanted 5, but why skip the other 3 if they actually sold exactly the same) and not 4 others too.

```
select
  ts.*
from  
  (
    select
      ss.*,
      rank() over (order by storesales) as storerank,
      rank() over (partition by store order by productsales) as productrank,
      rank() over (partition by store, product order by subproductsales) as subproductrank
    from
      (
        select 
          sd.*,
          sum(sales) over (partition by store) as STORESALES,
          sum(sales) over (partition by store, product) as PRODUCTSALES,
          sum(sales) over (partition by store, product, subproduct) as SUBPRODUCTSALES
        from 
          store_data sd
      ) ss 
  ) ts
where
  ts.storerank <= 2 and
  ts.productrank <= 3 and
  ts.subproductrank <= 4
```